# Bandwidth Optimization options locked Drupl 8.1.5

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I'm running Drupal 8.1.5 site. At /admin/config/development/performance the "Bandwidth Optimization" settings for "Aggregate CSS Files" and "Aggregate Javascript files" are disabled, so I cannot change their state. Can you help me, please.

[Options disable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XU3KS.jpg)

[My config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLjne.jpg)

regards

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have these set as variables in settings.php or setting.local.php.  Check those files for the appropriate variables (they should be obvious) and comment them out, or change them to your needs.

```
    $config['system.performance']['css']['preprocess'] = TRUE; // or FALSE
    $config['system.performance']['js']['preprocess'] = TRUE; // or FALSE
```

Make certain to flush the cache after making changes here.

Comment: Changes made to the config file will not show in /admin/config/development/performance, but they should nevertheless be active. I am a bit curious about why your options in /admin/config/development/performance are disabled. I wonder if you have a conflicting module, or have permissions issues.

Comment: Sure, in my file settings.local.php lines add $ config [ 'system.performance'] [ 'css'] [ 'preprocess'] = TRUE; // Or FALSE
$ Config [ 'system.performance'] [ 'js'] [ 'preprocess'] = TRUE; // Or FALSE

Install drush from www.drush.org console and entered the path of my project:

/ C / projects / cms

and wrote the "drush cr" command, wait to clean caches, review and already operating changes.